# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout Can't show list of users in app

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, kotlin

Can anyone help mi solve this problem? I want to show list of users in the app.

Logcat error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

User code

```
data class Users(val userId : String = "",
                 val name : String = "",
                 val email : String = "") {
                 }
```

UsersAdapter code

```
class UsersAdapter(var context : Context,
                   var userList : ArrayList<Users>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder>() {

    inner class UsersViewHolder(val adapterBinding : UsersItemBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(adapterBinding.root){}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UsersViewHolder {

        val binding = UsersItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return UsersViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UsersViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.adapterBinding.friendUserName.text = userList[position].name




    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return userList.size

    }


}
```

[MainActivity](https://pastebin.com/7NbMXXcd) code

Comment: Set Layout Manager to Recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in your Log you haven't attatched the adapter to your RecyclerView.
Try this in the MainActivity onCreate():

```
mainBinding.yourRecyclerView.adapter = userAdapter
```

Comment: i already have this in my code in 48 line of MainActivity.kt

Comment: Yes, but it's triggered by an event change listener. move the rv initialization outside of that method and put that inside the onCreate() method, as per the answer.

Comment: Error is solved, but it still not showing data in recycler view :(

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when update you want your recylerview, you must notifyDataSetChanged().
**Example**

```
mainBinding.yourRecylerview.adapter = userAdapter
userAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()
```